# Angular2, How to: Configure ui-router from multiple modules

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular-module

how to configure ui-router in angular 4 to use component from different modules? When I try use uiSref directive to change state from other modules, uiRouter doesn't reacts.

```
{
    name: 'app',
    abstract: true,
},
{
    name: 'app.login',
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        '@': LoginComponent
    }
}, {
    name: 'app.dashboard',
    url: '/dashboard',
    views: {
        '@': DashboardComponent
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using the features of named views then you should just reference the component directly, e.g.:

```
{
    name: 'app.login',
    url: '/login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
```

Another example in the UI-Router Sample App: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular/blob/master/src/app/contacts/contacts.states.ts

This will put the LoginComponent into the first ui-view element in the component defined by the parent state (named 'app' in this example).

This state definition should be in your feature module definition as a parameter of the forChild() method.

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    UIRouterModule.forChild({ states: FEATURE_MODULE_STATES }),
    ...
  ],
...
})
```

Also can be seen in the UI-Router Sample App: https://github.com/ui-router/sample-app-angular/blob/master/src/app/contacts/contacts.module.ts

Answer (score -2):

The following line that you currently have only states how to reach the above when navigated to as well as the display all in the address-bar of browser.

```
url: '/dashboard',
```

The below row needs to be added

```
templateUrl: 'folder/file.html'
```

Also it should look something like this:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('stateName', {
        url: '/file', <!-- Optional, "file" can be anything -->
        templateUrl: 'folder/file.html',
        controller: 'stateController' <!-- Optional -->
    })
```

Then the link will be triggered like this:

```
 <a ui-sref="stateName">ClickToGetTostateName</a>
```

Comment: He's talking about Angular 4 and not AngularJS